# How to add x86 and x64 VC++ 2019 Redistributables in single Inno Setup installer?

Tags: inno-setup, 32bit-64bit, pascalscript

I am trying to add both architectures [x32 and x64] VC++ 2019 (v14.26.28720.03) redistributable  in a single setup. I compiled successfully, but at runtime I got exception in `ExtractTemporaryFile('#VcInstall');`

```
;Version: v14.26.28720.03
[Setup]
#if arch == "x32"
  #define VcInstall "VC_redist.x86.exe"
#else
  #define VcInstall "VC_redist.x64.exe"
#endif

[Files]
Source: ".\Redist\{#VcInstall}"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\{#VcInstall}"; Parameters: "/q /norestart"; \
    Check: VC2019RedistNeedsInstall; Flags: waituntilterminated; \
    StatusMsg: "Installing VC++ 2019 redistributables..."
```

```pascal
[Code]
function VC2019RedistNeedsInstall: Boolean;
var 
  Version: String;
begin
  if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64', 'Version', Version)) then
  begin
    Log('VC Redist Version check : found ' + Version);
    Result := (CompareStr(Version, 'v14.26.28720.03')<0);
  end
    else 
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
  if (Result) then
  begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('#VcInstall');
  end;
end;
```

I got exception in runtime `ExtractTemporaryFile('#VcInstall');`

> Internal error: #VcInstall was not found

---

My solutions based on the answer by @Martin:

```pascal
[Code]
function VC2019RedistNeedsInstall(Arch: string): Boolean;
var 
  Version: String;
begin
  Result := True;
  if Arch = 'x64' then
  begin
    if RegKeyExists( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{CB4A0FDE-1126-4AE2-97C6-A243692C3D95}') then
    begin
      Log('VC Redist Version check : found ');
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
  if Arch = 'x32' then
  begin
    if RegKeyExists( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2F69FB2B-2C48-491C-B249-22C1BDCE1117}') then
    begin
      Log('VC Redist Version check : found ');
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The point of `Arch` parameter was to avoid repeating the code that differs only by `x86`/`x64`.  – If your variable part is the GUID, put the GUID to the parameter instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `VcInstall` code is a preprocessor code. It's executed on compile time, so it takes your development machine architecture into account.  What you do *not* want.

Instead, use [`Is64BitInstallMode`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_is64bitinstallmode) or [`IsWin64`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_iswin64) (read their documentation to pick the right one according to your needs). And you need to unconditionally include both versions of the redistributable to your installer.

```
[Files]
Source: ".\Redist\VC_redist.x86.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}
Source: ".\Redist\VC_redist.x64.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\VC_redist.x86.exe"; Parameters: "/q /norestart"; \
    Check: Is64BitInstallMode and VC2019RedistNeedsInstall('x86'); \
    Flags: waituntilterminated; \
    StatusMsg: "Installing VC++ 2019 redistributables..."
Filename: "{tmp}\VC_redist.x64.exe"; Parameters: "/q /norestart"; \
    Check: (not Is64BitInstallMode) and VC2019RedistNeedsInstall('x64'); \
    Flags: waituntilterminated; \
    StatusMsg: "Installing VC++ 2019 redistributables..."
```

```pascal
[Code]
function VC2019RedistNeedsInstall(Arch: string): Boolean;
var 
  Version: String;
begin
  Result :=
    RegQueryStringValue(
      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
      'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\' + Arch,
      'Version', Version)
  if Result then
  begin
    Log('VC Redist Version check : found ' + Version);
    Result := (CompareStr(Version, 'v14.26.28720.03') < 0);
  end;
end;
```

*(untested)*

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Martin's untested version, handling the case where the if statement fails:

```
[Code]
function VCRedistNeedsInstall(Arch: string): Boolean;
var 
  Version: String;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
       'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\' + Arch,
       'Version', Version) then
  begin
    Log('VC Redist Version check : found ' + Version);
    Result := (CompareStr(Version, 'v14.29.30139.0')<0);
  end
  else Result := True;
end;
```

This has been tested on x64 Win10 and Win11 systems using Inno Setup 6.2.1. Note that the version check string will vary depending on which version you're installing; it's the Product version seen in Properties > Details on the VC_redist executable you're distributing.